# Best way to check for all values in a Int

Tags: swift, if-statement, control-flow

I don't know if there is a better way of doing this, my solution works but just seems to repetitive.

I have a life indicator which is represented using an icon within `SpriteBuilder`, these are set to not visible, and then within source I have implemented the following code:

```
    lives = 3 // this is reduced or increased within game
    if (lives == 5) {
        lifeIcon1.visible = true
        lifeIcon2.visible = true
        lifeIcon3.visible = true
        lifeIcon4.visible = true
        lifeIcon5.visible = true
    } else if (lives == 4) {
        lifeIcon1.visible = true
        lifeIcon2.visible = true
        lifeIcon3.visible = true
        lifeIcon4.visible = true
    } else if (lives == 3) {
        lifeIcon1.visible = true
        lifeIcon2.visible = true
        lifeIcon3.visible = true
    } else if (lives == 2) {
        lifeIcon1.visible = true
        lifeIcon2.visible = true
    } else if (lives == 1) {
        lifeIcon1.visible = true
    }
```

This works fine but just seems repetitive, and is difficult to scale if I wanted to increase the lives to more than 5 at a later date.

Any suggestions?

Comment: variables with a number should be *always* replaced with an array.

Comment: Do you ever set `visible` to `false`? With the code you've shown us, none of the icons will ever get hidden – you'll appear to stay at max lives.

Comment: @originaluser2 they are set to `visible = false` within SpriteBuilder, and within my collision method the `lives` var is decremented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to set your `visible` to `false` when you decrease your lives, you can use something like this:

```
let lifeIcons = [lifeIcon1, lifeIcon2, lifeIcon3, lifeIcon4, lifeIcon5]

...

for (index, lifeIcon) in lifeIcons.enumerate() {
    lifeIcon.visible = index < lives
}
```

Or if you like using closures:

```
lifeIcons.enumerate().forEach{$1.visible = $0 < lives}
```

<sup>(Here `$1` is the current life icon in the iteration, and `$0` is the index of that icon)</sup>

The key point here is to use an *array*, instead of multiple variables to keep track of your life icons. You can then iterate through this array, using the indices of the elements in order to determine which icon they are. `enumerate()` is used in order to create a lazy sequence of pairs of elements with their indices.

In this case we can compare the indices of the elements with the current number of lives. Because indices are 0 based, we can check whether a given index is less than the current number of lives in order to determine whether it should be visible.

Comment: I have approved your answer as this was the most descriptive answer. Cheers

Comment: @Skelly1983 Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
let icons = [lifeIcon1, lifeIcon2, lifeIcon3, lifeIcon4, lifeIcon5]

icons[0..<lives].forEach { $0.visible = true }
```

It is similar to @Adam Heeg's answer, but the c-style loops are in the process of being deprecated. I would slice the array by subscript and use `forEach` instead.

Comment: Although i have used your approach I have accepted the answer from @originaluser2 as it was a more descriptive answer.

Comment: I agree, his is more complete :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have some other code which you don't wnat to change.  I would suggest the following.

Load all your lifeIcon's into an array then do the following.  (adjust for if you are 0 based or not).

```
for (int i = 0; i < lives; i++)
{
   lifeIconArray[i].visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Just FYI Adam, this will no longer work under Swift 3. C-style for loops are gone, you need to use 0..<lives.